# How does DQN convergence work in reinforcement learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, dqn, deep-rl

In supervised learning we have an unbiased target value, but in reinforcement learning this isn’t the case

The network predicts its own target value, now how exactly does it converge if the network predicts its target value

Can someone explain this to me ??

[image]

Comment: Initially, the target will be totally wrong but as the process goes on and on it will become closer to  the unbiased estimate, then it will eventually converge

Comment: Also, remember that this target is an unbiased estimate of the optimal Q value.

Comment: @Swakshar Deb Why does it get closer to the unbiased estimate, what exactly makes it that way

Comment: @Swakshar Deb why does it get closer to the unbiased estimate, what in that formula makes it the unbiased estimate

Comment: $q^{*}=E[R+\gamma \max_{a}Q(s_{t+1},a_{t+1})]$, that means $R+\gamma \max_{a} Q(s_{t+1},a_{t+1})$ is the unbiased estimate of $q^{*}$. So, if the iteration is large enough the target will eventually converge to the true estimate.

Comment: Oh I understand it now, thank you

Comment: @Swakshar Deb I would have liked the answer as a post for other users, but this is fine , Thanks a lot , I appreciate

Comment: @ChukwudiOgbonna Can you please describe in your own words your problem without taking screenshots? Can you edit your post to do this? If we take the time to read your posts and try to help, you should also take the time to write a question/post properly and show that you have put some effort into writing.

Comment: @SwaksharDeb I suggest that you a formal answer to the question (if you have one: I didn't read the comments above), given that comments are meant to be temporary.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the mathematical proof for the convergence. I have to look for it. If I get one I'll post it.